# Ansible file copy with sudo fails after upgrading to 1.9

Tags: linux, yaml, ansible

In a playbook, I copy files using sudo. It used to work... Until we migrated to Ansible 1.9... Since then, it fails with the following error message:

"ssh connection closed waiting for sudo password prompt"

I provide the ssh and sudo passwords (through the Ansible prompt), and all the other commands running through sudo are successful (only the file copy and template fail).

My command is:

ansible-playbook -k --ask-become-pass --limit=testhost -C -D playbooks/debug.yml

and the playbookd contains:

```
- hosts: designsync

  gather_facts: yes 

  tasks:
    - name: Make sure the syncmgr home folder exists
       action: file path=/home/syncmgr owner=syncmgr group=syncmgr mode=0755 state=directory
      sudo: yes
      sudo_user: syncmgr

    - name: Copy .cshrc file
      action: copy src=roles/designsync/files/syncmgr.cshrc dest=/home/syncmgr/.cshrc owner=syncmgr group=syncmgr mode=0755
      sudo: yes
      sudo_user: syncmgr
```

Is this a bug or did I miss something?

François.

Comment: I see you are copying .cshrc file across - which probably means the remote shell for the syncmgr user is csh. If this is the case then.. yes, this hangs (sudo + csh) with 1.9 and 1.8.4 at least. I've just checked 1.9.1 though and that seems to work OK.

Comment: What version are you running exactly? In Ansible 1.9.0.x there indeed was a sudo related bug, but I think it was only happening when you passed in roles, not in tasks. But if you're running 1.9.0.x you should upgrade to 1.9.1 and try again.

Comment: I'm in fact using 1.9.1...
The Ansible master is running RedHat-6.4 and the remote runs under CentOS-6.5... In case it matters (sudo 1.8.6, OpenSSH 5.3).

Answer (score 0):

Your playbook should look like:

```
- hosts: designsync

  gather_facts: yes 

  tasks:
    - name: Make sure the syncmgr home folder exists
      sudo: yes
      sudo_user: syncmgr
      file: 
        path: "/home/syncmgr" 
        owner: syncmgr
        group: syncmgr
        mode: 0755 
        state: directory

    - name: Copy .cshrc file
      sudo: yes
      sudo_user: syncmgr
      copy: 
        src: "roles/designsync/files/syncmgr.cshrc" 
        dest: "/home/syncmgr/.cshrc"
        owner: syncmgr 
        group: syncmgr 
        mode: 0755
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact version of Ansible you're using, there may be a bug with sudo_user (experienced it myself).

Trying changing your playbooks from "sudo_user" to "remote_user".